# Isotope/Masonry Corner Stamp

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am trying to add a corner stamp, however is not being displayed properly, i think there is an issue with the js code.

This is the official demo [Masonry Corner Stamp](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-corner-stamp.html)

This is where I am adding it to [Website](http://latinunit.org)

This is the JS [File](http://latinunit.org/wp-content/themes/videogrid-parent/js/isotope.js?ver=3.4.1)

I tried adding the following code on top of the JS code in the file but it still doesnt work..

```
  $.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function() {
    return true;
  };

  $.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function() {
    // layout-specific props
    this.masonry = {};
    this._getSegments();
    var i = this.masonry.cols;
    this.masonry.colYs = [];
    while (i--) {
      this.masonry.colYs.push( 0 );
    }

    if ( this.options.masonry.cornerStampSelector ) {
      var $cornerStamp = this.element.find( this.options.masonry.cornerStampSelector ),
          stampWidth = $cornerStamp.outerWidth(true) - ( this.element.width() % this.masonry.columnWidth ),
          cornerCols = Math.ceil( stampWidth / this.masonry.columnWidth ),
          cornerStampHeight = $cornerStamp.outerHeight(true);
      for ( i = Math.max( this.masonry.cols - cornerCols, cornerCols ); i < this.masonry.cols; i++ ) {
        this.masonry.colYs[i] = cornerStampHeight;
      }
    }
  };
```

[image: Screenshot]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This version here](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/xaE7F/) provided by the author (with filtering as added bonus) usually works.